# I don't understand the apply in following code in node js

Tags: node.js, apply

In the following code I can not understand what is the role of apply. and how the function works. I read many issues about apply, but still I can not understand it. I don't understand also the way it uses app.setup and after that it defines it as a function, and again using oldSetup in the same function.

```
const oldSetup = app.setup;
app.setup = function(...args){
const RESULT = oldSetup.apply(this, args);
//some other codes come here
return RESULT;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added comments to explain each step:

```js
// assume this is the initial state
const app = {
  setup (a, b, c) {
    return { a, b, c }
  }
}

// save a pointer to the original function
const oldSetup = app.setup

// override the key with a new function. this is done by coverage tools for example
app.setup = function (...args) {
  // if you don't know how many parameters the original function will get, you can use
  // the rest parameter feature to get them all in an array
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/rest_parameters
  // NOTE: you could use `arguments` too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

  // since you don't know how many parameters the original function expects, you call the apply
  // that accept an array of parameter and it will spread:
  // args[0] = first argument
  // args[1] = second argument
  // and so on...
  // https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/function/apply
  const RESULT = oldSetup.apply(this, args)

  // now you have the original result from the original function
  // you could change anything like "man in the middle" behaviour
  return RESULT
}

// it will print: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
console.log(app.setup(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

Comment: tanx a lot. I don't know how to thank you for all of your effort and teaching me all in details, although I should read it many times, but it is the answer of all my questions.
just to ask it, I have no app as an Object, it comes form app.js module, which uses this module.
But I think I can get the issue, I should read it in details.
It is appreciated!